# gzip a folder and its subfolders on the fly

Tags: java, gzip, gzipoutputstream

I have a big folder that I want to send a zipped version of it while saving on the sub-folders hierarchy.

currently I'm doing it by creating a large zip file and sending it.

I'm looking for a way to write the folder content to some outputstream that will be redirected to a socket output stream.

my motivation is to avoid from keeping large files in my machine on run time

I know how to do that for a single file, but have no idea how to process a folder with many sub folders and save the inner hierarchy...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're after, since `gzip` has no notion of files - just bytes to be compressed - you need an archive format like `tar` to combine a bunch of files and directories into a single stream, and then you can gzip that.

If you just want some compressed archive format, the JDK's [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) will let you use zip compression.

If you specifically need `gzip` format, there are a number of [implementstions of tar output streams](https://www.google.com/search?q=taroutputstream&oq=taroutputstream&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3.2317j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) out there - use one of those and pipeline it into the JDK's [gzip output stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).